# intersect graphs sharing a percentage of edges and vertices

Tags: r, igraph

I have a list of graphs (igraph format) and I would like to obtain a merge graph, which would be the intersection of those nodes and vertices that are shared a certain percentage trough all the graphs.

I know that igraph library has the function `graph.intersection()` but this function intersect all the vertices and nodes present in all the graphs.

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is a brief example

```
g1 <- graph.data.frame(df1, directed=F)
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,2,3,4), V2=c(3,3,5,5,5))
g2 <- graph.data.frame(df2, directed=F)
df3 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4), V2=c(3,3,5,5))
g3 <- graph.data.frame(df3, directed=F)
df4 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,1,2,3), V2=c(2,3,4,5))
g4 <- graph.data.frame(df4, directed=F)

get.edgelist(g1)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "3" 
[3,] "2"  "4" 
[4,] "3"  "5" 
[5,] "4"  "5" 

get.edgelist(g2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "3" 
[3,] "2"  "5" 
[4,] "3"  "5" 
[5,] "4"  "5" 

get.edgelist(g3)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "3" 
[3,] "3"  "5" 
[4,] "4"  "5" 

get.edgelist(g4)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "2" 
[2,] "1"  "3" 
[3,] "2"  "4" 
[4,] "3"  "5"
```

If I put all the graphs in a list:

```
mylist <- list(g1,g2,g3,g4)
```

And then apply the `graph.intersection()` function:

```
g.int <- graph.intersection(mylist, keep.all.vertices=FALSE)
```

The result is a graph with the following nodes and edges:

```
V(g.int)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

get.edgelist(g.int)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "3"  "5" 
[2,] "1"  "3"
```

What I want is to include those vertices and edges that appears in a certain percentage, in this example I would like to include edges present in 75% of the graphs. Thus, the optimal result would be:

```
V(g.int)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

get.edgelist(g.int)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "3"  "5" 
[2,] "1"  "3" 
[3,] "4"  "5"
```

Hope now it is more clear

Comment: As written, this question is really broad and difficult to answer in the general case. Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include some sample data as well as desired output. This would make your question much easier to answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding the adjacency matrices?

Comment: Not @WillBeason, maybe I should give it a try

Comment: Typed up as an answer. Should work on any list of graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a graph of all of the edges in the graphs, then eliminate edges which do not appear often enough.

```
library(igraph)

# generate graphs
edgeset <- combn(1:20, 2)

graphs <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  graphs[[i]] <- graph(i + edgeset[, sample(ncol(edgeset), 150)])
}

# Get a list of all edges in all graphs
myedges <- lapply(graphs, get.edgelist)

# Make a graph of all of the edges including overlap
uniongraph <- graph(do.call(rbind, myedges))

# Eliminate edges not overlapped enough
resultgraph <- graph.adjacency(get.adjacency(uniongraph) >= 0.75 * length(graphs))
```

Comment: Your approach @WillBeason works when the graphs have the same number of vertices, but whether the graphs have different number of vertices, the adjacency matrices could not be reduced, right?

Comment: Just add the nodes not in each graph to the graphs and make sure they're all sorted correctly.

Comment: Thanks @WillBeason, I will try your suggestion

Comment: Figured it out and updated. It now works for graphs even if they do not share the same number of vertices.